# Conditional Blogger,

Tags: html, blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

How do I make this CSS appear in every blog tag, but I don't want it to appear in specific tags

This code does the opposite, it specifies which tag should appear in the css, I would like a code that could show the css everywhere except in certain tags

```
  <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel in [&quot;car&quot;, &quot;Identity&quot;, &quot;Brand&quot;]'>

<style>
    body { background: #e2ad44 }
  </style> 

</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the logical operator `not` to reverse condition:

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel not in ["car", "Identity", "Brand"]'>
  <style>
    body { background: #e2ad44 }
  </style> 
</b:if>
```